# How to open a pdf file in binary format

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework, pypdf

I want to read the metadata of pdf files so i am using pyPdf package  but for some files i am facing error (i.e;PdfFileReader stream/file object is not in binary mode,it may not be read correctly)

Comment: If you know just help me but with out giving proper answer you are just giving minus to my question

Comment: I didn't downvote you but the reason people would do so is that you haven't shared any code nor told us what you have tried. Have a look here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the file in binary mode:

```
from pyPdf import PdfFileReader
with open('document.pdf', 'rb') as f:
    pdf = PdfFileReader(f)
```